# Why can I assume the force to be constant in this particular interval?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring, integration, calculus

If I have force, or any function $f(z)$, I was told that I can assume it to be constant only in the interval $dz$.

However, in this case, I had to calculate the work done by the spring force as a function of $y$
[image]

Over here, I assumed the spring force, which is a function of its elongation $x$ ($F = -kx$) to be constant in the interval $dy$ and integrated and **this gave me the correct answer**

I want to know why the error vanished over here. Shouldn't spring force only be constant in the interval $dx$ and not $dy$?

I also want to know, in general, if I have a function, how to decide whether it is constant in some particular interval/in which cases the error will vanish as I take the limit and integrate.

**Note:**  I do know I can assume a function $f(x)$ to be constant in the interval $[x,x+dx)$ while integrating, but over here I've assumed it to be constant in the interval $dy$. I want to know why I can do that and also if I can assume a force/function to be constant in any infinitesimal interval such as $Rdθ$, $dy\over cosϕ$,$dz$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is, in general, by definition. $dx$ and $dy$ are defined in such a way that the force *can be assumed to be constant* in such an interval.

That's the general case, the way we use infinitesimals in physical problems mostly. Exceptions to this may occur.

Answer (score 0):

You did a coordinate transformation from $x$ to $\theta$ to $y$. You are doing a normal integration. In such, you can assume the function to be constant for the interval $\mathrm dX$ for any $X$, as long as the function $f(X)$ is *smoothly differentiable*. That means that $f'(X)$ does not have any jumps. One eample of function that do not work would be $f(x) = |x|$ at value $x = 0$.

A function which can be differentiated smoothly infinitely often can be expanded into a *Taylor series*. This might be a circular definition when looking at analytic functions, but that shall not bother us here. We can find the approximation
$$ f(x - a) = f(a) + f'(a) [x - a] + \frac 12 f''(a) [x-a]^2 + \ldots \,.$$
When we look at the interval $[x, x + \mathrm dx)$, we look at an infinitely small interval. We can call this size $\epsilon$. When you integrate, you sum up slices of the function of size $\epsilon$. Since we do the limit $\epsilon \to 0$, we say that only terms of $\epsilon^1$ are interesting, terms with $\epsilon^2$ or higher powers will tend to zero faster than anything else of interest.

If we integrate in the interval $[x, x + \mathrm dx)$, we can take the value of the function at $x$ and use the Taylor expansion to get the value at $x + \mathrm dx$:
$$ f(x + \mathrm dx) = f(a) + f'(a) \, \mathrm dx + \frac 12 f''(a) [\mathrm dx]^2 + \ldots \,.$$

Then you do the Riemann sums and compute the area of the rectangles, you multiply again with $\mathrm dx$ and sum up those areas:
$$ \int \mathrm dx \, f(x) \simeq \sum_i \mathrm dx \left[ f(x_i) + f'(x_i) \, \mathrm dx + \frac 12 f''(x_i) [\mathrm dx]^2 + \ldots \right] \,.$$
But now we have this additional power of the small number $\mathrm dx$ in there. And $[\mathrm dx]^2$ is already “too small to count”. Therefore the only interesting term within the interval $[x, \mathrm dx)$ is the leading term. So we only need to keep the $f(x_i)$ term in the sum and not the derivatives. That means that the function can be assumed constant in the infinitesimal interval.

Comment: I do know that I can assume a function $f(z)$ to be constant in the interval $dz$. But in my case, I have assumed $f(z)$ to be constant in an unrelated interval $dy$.

Comment: It's not unrelated! You have the explicit transformation with the tangent. And that is differentiable, so infinitesimal internals get mapped to infinitesimal ones.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on that statement in your answer? Also, in general, can we assume **any** force or function, in general, to be constant in any infinitesimal increment such as $Rd\theta$ ,$dy/cos \phi$, $dz$ etc.?